# Visit visa and work visa

Tags: visas, work, new-zealand

I'm going to work in New Zealand and my work visa will start after my arrival. I will enter as a tourist before with a waiver (I'm from Canada). I've been told that I need to go out of the country and return to validate my work visa. Can I just go to immigration at the airport?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to leave New Zealand to switch visa types. From [Can I apply for any other visa while on a visitor visa in New Zealand?](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/already-have-a-visa/my-situation-has-changed/visit/can-i-apply-for-any-other-visa-while-on-a-visitor-visa-in-new-zealand):

> ## Apply to stay longer
>
> If you're already in New Zealand and have a visa you can reapply for the same visa or apply for a different one.

Comment: Not sure this answers the question. OP *already has* the other visa, so they can't apply again.

Comment: @MJeffryes: It doesn't matter if the OP already holds a not-yet-valid work visa when entering the country. The situation is the same. New Zealand does not require people to leave and re-enter to "validate" anything.

Comment: Fair enough, but the page you linked, as far as I can tell doesn’t say that (maybe I’m missing something)